# Deleting duplicates based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my code:

```
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path
import os 
import pandas as pd 

df=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1': ['red','blue','red','red','green','red','yellow', 'red', 'cyan', 'purple', 'pink', 'black', 'orange'],
        'col2': ['red', 'green','orange'],
    }
)
```

The desired output would be to eliminate every value that appears on `col1` and also appears on `col2`, then drop `col2` and then export the document to an excel spread sheet.

The desired df would look like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1': ['blue', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'purple', 'pink', 'black',]
    }
)
```

As of now my code looks this this, but it's not giving me the intended result as it does not drop the duplicate values.

```
df = df.drop(df[(df['col1'] == df['col2'])].index) 
df = df.drop(['col2'], inplace=True)
os.startfile(File_path, index=False)
```

Here is the updated code:

```
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path
import os 
import pandas as pd 

df_output = Path.home().joinpath("Desktop", "Remaining colors.xlsx")

df=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1': ['red','blue','red','red','green','red','yellow', 'red', 'cyan', 'purple', 'pink', 'black', 'orange'],
        'col2': ['red', 'green','orange'],
    }
)

(df.loc[~df['col1'].isin(df["col2"]), ['col1']])

df = df.drop(columns='col2')
df.to_excel(df_output, index=False)
os.startfile(df_output)
```

Comment: if you have so few values, converting to a `set()` intermediately and rebuilding the column may work well

Comment: The example data frame you gave is not a valid data frame -

Comment: @Psidom I'm very new to python and have been just converting `df = pd.read_excel` and was not aware this was not a valid df. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `isin` and boolean indexing:

```
(df.loc[~df['col1'].isin(df['col2']), ['col1']]
   .to_excel('filename.xlsx', index=False)
)
```

Output:

```
      col1
1     blue
6   yellow
8     cyan
9   purple
10    pink
11   black
```

Used input:

```
      col1    col2
0      red     red
1     blue   green
2      red  orange
3      red     NaN
4    green     NaN
5      red     NaN
6   yellow     NaN
7      red     NaN
8     cyan     NaN
9   purple     NaN
10    pink     NaN
11   black     NaN
12  orange     NaN
```

Comment: So, I added the following code: `df = df["col2"].drop()`, and apparently I do get the output I desire, but I also get the following error" `ValueError: Need to specify at least one of 'labels', 'index' or 'columns'`

Comment: @JoseDanielRojas did you mean `dropna()`? or `df.drop(columns='col2')`?

Comment: I added: `df.drop(columns='col2')`, and I do get the output on excel but with an error on the terminal which is: ` ValueError: Need to specify at least one of 'labels', 'index' or 'columns'`. And the file now does not start on it's own.

Comment: can you provide the full code for me to reproduce it?

Comment: sure thing! I edited the original comment and added the complete code at the end. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Except for the DataFrame constructor (I used: `'col2': ['red', 'green','orange']+[np.nan]*10`), the code works fine for me, no error.

Comment: Yeah the error was on my side. Sorry about that, and thanks for the help. I forgot to place the `df=` --> `df = (df.loc[~df['col1'].isin(df['col2']), ['col1']]
   .to_excel('filename.xlsx', index=False)`